# CakePHP can't get ajax GET working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I can't seem to get AJAX POST or GET working with my CAKEPHP site. I am trying to create autocomplete but can't seem to submit or fetch the data using ajax.  I can get auto complete working using tags but I cannot display the data from my table. I am not sure what is going wrong if i'm not using the right url or some other problem.
Here is my search.ctp

```
<?php use Cake\Routing\Router; ?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->input('id', ['type' => 'text']); ?>

<script>
    $.ajax({
    type:       "POST",
    url:        "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'Invoices', 'action' => 'search')); ?>",
    success:    function(response) {
        $("#id").autocomplete({ source: response });
    }
});
</script>
```

Here is my search function in my InvoicesController.

```
    public function search()
{
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) 
    {
        $name = $this->request->query['term'];
        $resultArr = $this->Invoices
    ->find()
    ->where(
        ['Invoices.id LIKE' => ($name . '%')],
        ['Invoices.id' => 'string']
    );

        $resultsArr = [];
        foreach ($resultArr as $result) 
        {
             $resultsArr[] = (strval($result['id']));
        }

        $this->set('resultsArr', $resultsArr);
        // This line is what handles converting your array into json
        // To get this to work you must load the request handler
        $this->set('_serialize', ['resultsArr']);


    }
}
```

This is the error that is produced when I try to type in an ID.
[image]

This is what i want to produce which I have been able to do by using an array in search.ctp
[image]

and here is my table I am trying to fetch the IDs from.
[image]

Comment: It doesn't even seem to be finding your PHP file in the first place so the query or the table aren't the problem. Perhaps your AJAX request has a malformed URL. Write the expected URL to the console and see if it's correct.

Comment: I guess it's also possible that your Cake routing isn't  set up correctly.

Comment: You should inspect the network tab to figure out what is being sent and received, also check your error logs. The request handler component btw. should be loaded in the `initialize()` method  (which it normally already is by default in `AppController`).

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods.

1. `$this->request->query('term');`
2. `$_REQUEST['term'];`